# How to Factorial only 5 numbers?

Tags: javascript, factorial

I have a factorial code but when it will find the result of the factorial it will get the result of the whole factorial.

Im looking for a code that finds the factorial of the last 5 factorials of a number? For example, 10! ? I need only the result of 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 = 30240? How do I do that?

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var n = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter the Number:"));
        var result = fact(n);
        window.alert("Factorial of the given number " + result);
        function fact(n)
        {
            if(n == 0)
                return 1;
            else 
                return (n*fact(n-1));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you analyze the code you show ? Do you understand it ?

Comment: Basically you do: `10!/5!` (`fact(10)/fact(5)`)

Answer (score 0):

As MinusFour already noted: you want `10!/5!`. You can do it that way and compute both values and divide. They divide exactly, no worry about fractions (proof omitted). But it is size-restricted, you cannot do e.g. `100!95!` in JavaScript without a big-integer library and even with a big-integer library things like `1000000!/999998!` will need a lot of computation time (both are numbers with over 5 million decimal digits).

My suggestion: no tricks, just compute it linearly like you would do it by hand:

```
function fact(n,k){
  var t = 1;
  for(var i = n;i>k;i--){
    t *= i;
  }
  return t;
}
console.log(fact(10,5));
```

The first one must be the bigger one, both must be positive, all other checks and balances are omitted, too.